# Python script to monitor devices

Tags: python, monitoring

I am stuck in one area. I have few devices in MySQL database that has been set for different polling intervals. As an example, total I have 4 devices, 2 of which user wants to poll at every 5 minutes interval, other two at 10 minutes, and one should be polled at every 7 minutes.

I want to build one solution in python that picks those devices from the database and their polling intervals and then start polling these devices on their defined polling interval continuously.

As I can't create multiple polling scripts (one for each) as it will over-utilized the CPU resources. And if the number of devices reached up to 1000, then it will be a problem to poll all 1000 at once. It's more like a monitoring solution that keeps on running and monitor devices.

I am really stuck at this point. I'll appreciate your help with this.

Comment: which platform ? Linux ?

Comment: I want it to be platform independent, if possible, else on linux

Comment: I'd recommend `collectd` if it were linux. But i think there's something compatible for windows too. #whyreinventthewheel ?

Comment: But, what if I want to do it by python, something like poller or worker, that polls the devices at their defined polling interval, and continues to run forever

Comment: What do you mean devices? servers? URL end points?

Comment: Yes, the servers

Answer (score 0):

Generating a worker for each interval will do the job. The code for the same would look somewhat like this:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

intervals = [1, 2, 3] # hardcoding it to check, fetching it from db would be better

def generate_poll_worker(interval):
    def poll_devices():
        while True:
            # fetch the devices and poll them
            sleep(interval * 60)

    return poll_devices

def worker_process(interval):
    poll = generate_poll_worker(interval)
    poll()

workers = []

for interval in intervals:
    worker = Process(target=worker_process, args=(interval,))
    worker.start()
    workers.append(worker)

for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```

Comment: Can you please provide a script that gives me a idea on how to do it ?

Comment: Great, I got your point and is efficient solution. can you make it more clear if I give you an example of 3 such intervals, lets say 3 mins, 5 mins and 10 mins

Comment: In that case, fetching the distinct values in the poll_interval column of the table and converting it to a list would give you `[3, 5, 7]`. You can iterate through that list to generate a worker for each interval.